# Help identifying contents of strange email

Tags: encryption, email, json

My wife received a weird email from an address neither of us recognizes. The structure of most of the message reminds me of JSON. What do I have here? Is is possible to decipher?

Thanks!

The message is as follows:

```
From: <tiennemargherioms18@yahoo.com>
Date: Jul 16, 2017 9:42 PM
Subject: ssocracy
To: 
Cc: 

undresses
X-vvgukall: bunoecabtev
X-sdtrlao: egvxxnvsdyuxjldspgk
X-eagwube: hhyicmg
X-vbjxoy: tdqmkeplmdjaq
X-qbudgi: rydtqkp
X-tlryf: wrgfr
X-tblpgokqc: psxikry
X-smfmbl: hugewroqwkblmppngd
X-blklrc: cbharkgcaof
X-ueoghdtbf: majvktgnnbib
X-fvudck: biyppbogprcibdpwxn
X-wpolf: hcpxtjjriexckeu
X-wpwnvdag: mosgnl
X-ncrsovgqn: ndvjskpylchdjtrq
X-xjlggyi: lppinkekm
X-fyosngkba: nwlbbepoymikjdnt
X-taenqu: brpscxrcpdbussy
X-saefla: xqujikasbtfcad
X-nlgkes: pdvehweq
X-irtqetv: cetwegjkfp
X-SHNBYV: wsgpk
X-lygpiekk: fplbavqdfpyovgnml
X-wfocyt: jbwaggbodx
X-hrgyelja: sriqmegrn
X-vldgkmde: jcvueviqx
X-vjsaxdidm: ytmypvwiqxxjlnqik
X-jakjqxst: feewg
X-QHMTJ: ysajswiklqilnp
X-HETBBHD: aqunrbyieyjw
X-aejmoltl: bbryqnesldcinjbvw
X-EHDQOJ: kfjvkwi
X-dseshdisw: spqbqoqoytlpexof
X-gfkjbgq: wsliapphuuaikwixm
X-juaqmg: apvnoflebbk
X-jobyybspc: dilci
X-rajlx: bwodoqnqkrkqbrfhlf
X-RXJNQPYLV: fpdori
X-yvmjgqhx: hskbjwrolybw
X-RJISVODSY: aarohumkjpcquhxeis
X-dpyar: jhcujit
X-mlqrlh: jmsoqseooxyprxm
X-hmryvtgtl: qxieivmswjvoviyhno
X-vhqhle: sedmh
X-jbnbh: fdvwlqkqkyvnmvymixr
X-ormair: jjfbsjuplq
X-qeblmyi: xpftoqcdrqartglka
X-gbcbrm: kiulllfj
X-kfvdowo: tymhoxiauy
X-nfdnplts: oonpgottfxewasly
X-yjaobxuv: ftlelxgchihfnotumj
X-GWPCOMYCS: cxdtls
X-glgdvv: fhojicglytigpmtf
X-sxmuh: ymlcgkiovouosw
X-jfyhwcksp: bgehccnfxf
X-bwyytkh: dvvrvatrukgxplylew
X-dxslpv: ftlqhpoesm
X-xvohiwchc: qdiqfvfalhjco
X-SROBVORYE: ysavnxgtqwgsgghqh
X-wynsmini: wjbdragpkyaam
X-axmsviyc: ymbbcufbaqo
X-xefrccyjj: pximptbtd
X-kujmvk: qnuug
X-MNLSWUIV: auxnpacurmfrujum
X-dejvsh: qnonio
X-lyunqeyf: usghsc
X-gbaurq: huuth
X-ategv: lmvfufagvl
X-rrurhdtgy: sojuqbaxtli
X-nubuupdy: yypgrguffr
X-xwlxke: kejxkhxliefqoj
X-DRRER: yofmmqb
X-rpwhnxe: pgmjuguvhrnhkoue
X-qjuahc: msykajl
X-eushunrdf: drlxddnveel
X-kdvbkeybr: aoavpjsbv


g
pastis
tes
saliv2764446
```

Comment: they are random strings

Comment: Although at first they appear like odd headers they appear to be utterly random, it's not json and doesn't look encrypted. I'd block the sender and ignore it.

Comment: This is NOT the raw message.  If you want somebody to help to deciper the real culprits, look for your email client raw message display function, copy and paste the raw message to https://pastebin.com/ and provide the url.

Comment: Subject: ssocray -- Single Sign On? Username/Password that are weakly encrypted possibly?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like weakly encrypted username - password pairs, with passwords containing 5 to 20 characters.
Ain't nobody got time to decrypt this.

Why not asking Tienne what's up?
If you don't get a response, block him/her and move on.